# When I activate my scence lights my world lights (HDRI) no longer work

Tags: lighting, scene, hdri, world

When I activate my scence lights my world lights (HDRI) no longer work, also when I disabled all light it works fine.

[image: Hdri is correct when scene light disabled]

when light enabled hdri doesn't work
[image: when light enabled hdri dosent work]

also outside]
[image: also outside]

when scene light on hdri doesent work
[image: when scene light on hdri doesent work]